# Using External Functions in a CTE on Snowflake

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Is it possible to call an external function that is integrated with an API within a CTE (Common Table Expressions) within Snowflake?

Please see the example below for what I'm trying.

```
with question_batch as (
    select *
    from (
        values('who are you?')
            ,('what are you?')
            ,('how are you?')
        ) as t(question)
    )
select 
    qb.question
    ,external_api(qb.question) as response
from question_batch qb;
```

I get the following error when attempting to call the API as shown in the code:

> Error: "data" JSON array must contain exact number of rows as the
> request. Response batch expected to have 3 rows, but received 1 rows.

I can see in the API logs that the API is called successfully for the first question and it returns a successful response.

Comment: Hi - your external function call is not in a CTE, it’s in the main SQL statement. The error message implies that you’re not calling the external function correctly but without knowing the definition of the function/api it’s not possible to be certain